# Dynamically creating a grid using lists

Tags: c#, list, grid

Im trying to create a dynamic grid with columns equal to the amount of days in a month (will add that feature later after i get the grid to appear) and rows equal to the amount of objects within the emplist list.

This is my code so far.

```
Grid dategrid = new Grid();
dategrid.Width = 400;
dategrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
dategrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
dategrid.ShowGridLines = true;
dategrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DimGray);
List<ColumnDefinition> columnlist = new List<ColumnDefinition>();
List<RowDefinition> rowlist = new List<RowDefinition>();
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
{
    columnlist.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    dategrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(columnlist[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < Control.empList.Count; i++)
{
    rowlist.Add(new RowDefinition());
    dategrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowlist[i]);
    rowlist[i].Height = new GridLength(45);
}
```

The code compiles, but no grid appears on the form.
I feel like I'm missing something real basic here, but can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `dategrid.Bind()`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show you adding the grid to the page anywhere. So far all you have shown is instantiating a building the grid *in memory*. You need something like `gridSpace.controls.add(datagrid)` where gridspace is a container on the page. Something like `<div id="gridspace" runat="server"></div>` (any other container will do...). Or (if this is winforms) to a panel or other container on the form....